# Multiple Variables Explode and Insert to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I checked for a possible solution in the site and found no solution. I have a form which has two text fields for the user to enter Name and Mobile Number. By default the page shows only two fields. If the user wants he can add more. The problem is, I am unable to insert these multiple data into DB. Please see below. I do no have 10 reputations to post images. Hence I am giving an external link.

1) The initial form
http://postimg.org/image/qiojxjrcx/

2) Clicking the plus symbol, user can add more fields
    http://postimg.org/image/zaetpokbx/

3) The fields added dynamically using Jquery have unique id's and a class. The script below is for getting the values of Staff Name and Mobile Number 
a) Script for Getting Staff Name

```js
var addstaffname = new Array();
 $('input[class="addstaff"]').each(function() {
       addstaffname.push(this.value);
    });
```

b) Script for Getting Mobile Number

```js
var addstaffmob = new Array();
 $('input[class="addstaffmob"]').each(function() {
       addstaffmob.push(this.value);
});
```

I am getting the values by using the class for Staff Name and Mobile. And through ajax I am posting these values in PHP.

```js
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"../../ajax.php",
   data:'addstaffname='+addstaffname+'&addstaffmob='+addstaffmob,
   cache:false,
   success: function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    
   }
   })
```

In ajax.php, I am storing these values into variables.

```
if(isset($_POST['addstaffname']))
{
$addstaffname = $_POST['addstaffname'];
$addstaffmob = $_POST['addstaffmob'];
$addstaffnameexploded = explode(',',$addstaffname);
$addstaffmobexploded = explode(',',$addstaffmob);
}
```

I am using explode as I have multiple values and all the values I get are CSV's from Jquery. I have a table called staff with three columns, staff_id,staff_name,staff_mobile and staff_id is PK and Auto Increment. My question is how do I insert staff name and mobile in the same row. Lets say we got staff name as A,B,C and mobile numbers as 100,200,300 from the form, I need to insert into MySQL DB with these values. So A will have mobile 100, B will have 200 and so on... If I had only one explode, I could easily use foreach loop and iterate. Very simple. I am going mad on how to insert data with this scenario. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to create a form and use an array in the input

```
<input type="text" name="addstaffname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="addstaffmob[]" value="" />
```

then send the entire form using ajax

```
$("#form").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'});
```

(ajaxForm is a jquery plugin [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/))

and when you collect the data in php, you'll just have to do a foreach one of its key variables, some like this.

```
$addstaffname = $_POST['addstaffname'];
$addstaffmob  = $_POST['addstaffmob'];

foreach($addstaffname as $key=>$name){
  echo "Your name is " . $name . " and your phone is " . $addstaffmob[$key];
}
```

obviously you need to make a cast to vars, for sql injection or etc

Comment: thank you very much. i used serialize and foreach loop and it worked. However I used $.ajax instead of $.ajaxForm. Could you also please tell me how to get the success information when using $.ajaxForm(any fiddle would be great)

Comment: I am sorry, i used a sample of a jquery plugin "http://malsup.com/jquery/form/" you are right with serialize method